# Prevent google indexing dev sites

Tags: seo

My webhost lets me set up site aliases (for example, example.111.222.333.444.sth.co) as urls to access websites i'm developing. Without me doing anything, google seems to index sites/pages on here. What's the cleanest way to stop Google seeing anything that's under development?

Comment: See also [Dev site indexed by Google](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25752/dev-site-indexed-by-google) for what to do if your dev site has already been indexed.